# Ошибка при преодолении устройства CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine is required

Tags: android, android-wear

Пытаюсь определить форму экрана устройства таким способом:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "Application onCreate()");

    Engine engine = new Engine();
}


public class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    boolean mIsRound;
    int mChinSize;

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        mIsRound = insets.isRound();
        mChinSize = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
    }

}
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
Error:(31, 12) error: an enclosing instance that contains CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine is required
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на public static class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine

Comment: @АндроидАндроид в смысле? у меня же и стоит public

Comment: забыл статик дописать)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид не помогло(

Comment: Понял. Думаю тут вот это курить надо http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @АндроидАндроид ясно, пример с офф. сайта просто, я думал мож в библиотеке какой то проблема или еще че..